# Dividing each edge of a polygon into one-thirds

Tags: geometry

Begin with an equilateral triangle. Divide each edge into $3$ equal parts and cut off the corners. Continue this procedure indefinitely. Does this create a regular polygon at each stage?

I don't think that it creates that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cut off the edge'?

Comment: @TobyMak I think it means "cut off the corner".

Comment: You divide the edges into 3 equal parts. For two consecutive edges, you select the two divisions at the endpoint and cut off that triangular edge

Comment: [Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420000/efficient-way-of-performing-geometrical-operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only the first one (an hexagon) is a regular polygon. Once you reach the second step (a dodecagon), it is already a non-regular polygon.

I have programmed it (see below).

Have a look

- at the general shape (Fig. 1) where all the intermediate constructions are displayed and
- at a magnification of one side (Fig. 2).

Edit : (an answer to the area issue) : Taking $n=10$ successive cropping operations for this equilateral triangle $T$ with sidelength $2$ , I find 0.989743318... for the approximate value of the area of the limit shape, and I *guess* that the exact value is $4 \sqrt{3}/7$ (coincidence on nearly 15 digits for this value $n=10$ !). As the area of $T$ is $\sqrt{3}$, it means that the ratio of the area of the inside of the limit shape to the area of initial triangle should be the very simple result $4/7$.

How can we obtain a proof of this result ? I there a trick of the kind Archimedes was using for computing areas, or maybe with more sophisticated tools ?

[image]

[image]

Matlab program :

```
 clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;axis off;
 i=complex(0,1);
 T=[-1,1,sqrt(3)*i]; % equilateral triangle with sidelength 2
 plot([T,T(1)],'color',[0,0,1]);
 n=5; % depth
 Q=zeros(1,3*2^n);
 for k=1:n
    R=[T,T(1:3)]; % T is "augmented" for cycling purposes
    for p=0:length(T)
         Q(2*p+1)=(R(p+1)+2*R(p+2))/3;
         Q(2*p+2)=(2*R(p+2)+R(p+3))/3;
    end;
    T=Q(1:3*2^k);
    plot([T,T(1)],'color',[k/n,0,1-k/n]);
 end;
 [~,A]=convhull(real(T),imag(T));% A = area
```

Comment: Yes, true.  What's the area of the polygon at the end? Also, what's the shape of the conic that you get?

Comment: 1) The limit area can surely be calculated exactly ; I will try to obtain an approximation of it. 2) It is not a conic.

Comment: Sorry yes. It's not a conic. Yes, do tell the limit area once you are done calculating it.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for spotting the reference. I recommend in particular the following link : (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51008/limit-of-a-sequence-of-polygons).